# Cannot find nav_core and costmap_2d on ros-indigo

Tags: ros, navigation, nav-core, costmap-2d, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to run `rosmake robotino` for the [robotino-ros-pkg](/http://svn.openrobotino.org/robotino-ros-pkg/trunk/) in ros-indigo installed from the .torrent file for 64 bit.
I have set up my workspace with rosbuild according to [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment). My environment variable ROS_PACKAGE_PATH looks like this:

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH = /home/viki/indigo_ws/sandbox/robotino-ros-pkg:/home/viki/indigo_ws/sandbox:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

When I run rosmake I get the following error:

```
[rospack] Error: package 'robotino_local_planner' depends on non-existent package 'nav_core' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update
```

I ran `rosdep update` but nothing happened. The same goes for the package `costmap_2d`. When I check the share directory in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, these packages are indeed not there. However, I managed to find them on ros-hydro.

What am I missing here? Where are these package on ros-indigo or how can these packages be installed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192241/cannot-find-nav_core-and-costmap_2d-on-ros-indigo/) by [adina](https://answers.ros.org/users/20153/adina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

nav_core and costmap_2d are ROS packages and part of the navigation stack. It is available for indigo, so you should install ros-indigo-navigation.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adina](https://answers.ros.org/users/20153/adina/) on 2014-09-09**:
Thanks. It works like a charm.